# Cross domain CSS Loading

Tags: css, cross-domain

I am building a suite of websites (108) using the a common theme. To save space and time building them i used a common CSS file. At the moment the css file for each template gets loaded from one location - http:///whatever.com/css/globalcssfilename.css

My question is. Will it be faster to load the CSS file this way?http://192.168.0.100/css/globalcssfilename.css

Logically it makes sense that the css file location would not have to located using dns lookup because the ip address is there already?

I should also mention

The 107 sites are all parked (add-on) domains on a master domain(108th site). thus the 107 secondary sites are all subdirectories on the main site. but i have tried using many variations of "../../" but it does not work. only way to call the CSS file that works is with the domain link.

The user might not visit all the sites but this is mainly for me to change a CSS file in one place and make it affect all 108 sites.

ps... this also applies to some of the JS files in my theme.

Comment: It depends. Is the file already cached because the user visited one of the other sites? Do you hit the maximum parallel requests for the domain + browser? Where is the file served from (location) ?

Comment: My Apologies...editing my original post to include more info

Comment: As far as I know DNS lookups are cached and whenever you’re connected to whatever.com the DNS lookup is already completed and can be used for every other resources on this page without a need to refresh the lookup.

Comment: Thank you...  KittMedia makes total sense ~!